# regex in bash-script to exclude certain word

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, regex-negation

I want to exclude "cgs" and "CGS" but select all other data.

Testdata:

exclude this-->

C

```
SP999_20151204080019_0054236_000_CGS.csv
CSP999_20151204080019_0054236_000_cgs.csv
```

accept all other.

I tried something like this `.*([Cc][Gg][Ss]).*` to select the *cgs*, but I don't understand the exclude thing =)  It must be a filename_pattern without grep.

Kind Regards,

Bobby

Comment: You can use awk with `[Cc][Gg][Ss]` as field separator.

Comment: grep -v cgs (-v for exlude)
Or use egrep (for regex).

Comment: `if [[ "${short_filename}" =~ ${regex} ]] # all exclude cgs
    then
        local out_target="${intern_file/${in_dir}/${out_dir}}"
    fi` therefore i need only the regex without grep and so on

Answer (score 1):

Does it **have** to be a regexp? You can easily do it with a glob pattern, if you set in your script

```
shopt -o extglob
```

to enable extended globbing. You would then use the pattern

```
!(*[Cc][Gg][Ss]*)
```

to generate all entries which do NOT have CGS in their name.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep --invert-match --ignore-case cgs < filenames_list
```

Comment: @Soren, the OP seemed a bit vague on that point, (his description is as you noted, but his code says otherwise), and therefore allowing `cGs` to slip through seems over-literal.

Comment: I don't think it is vague -- he want to match and exclude anything with "cgs" and "CGS"

Comment: @user3181885 could you please clarify whether you wanted to exclude `cGs`?

Comment: Hi,

i have the solution for my regex --> `*[^:CGS|cgs:].*` 

this regex exclude all CGS or cgs in my testdata =) 

thx for your help

Comment: @user3181885, glad to hear that, but whether you initially wanted to exclude cGs is more of a "yes" or "no" question.  Or put another way, did you initially even consider the possibility of input data containing cGs?  Inquiring minds want to know...

Comment: hi, there is no possibility of data containing cGs.

Answer (score 1):

#### *`extglob`* [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) option

Try this:

```
ls -ld $path/!(*[cC][gG][sS].csv)
```

And have a look at

```
man -Pless\ +/extglob bash
```

> ```
>   If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several
>   extended  pattern  matching operators are recognized.  In the following
>   description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated
>   by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the fol‐
>   lowing sub-patterns:
>
>          ?(pattern-list)
>                 Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
>          *(pattern-list)
>                 Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
>          +(pattern-list)
>                 Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
>          @(pattern-list)
>                 Matches one of the given patterns
>          !(pattern-list)
>                 Matches anything except one of the given patterns
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Following may help you:

```
ls |grep -iEv "cgs"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using invert match of grep:

```
grep -v 'cgs\|CGS' <filelist
```

Or,

```
ls | grep -v 'cgs\|CGS'
```